# PHP, MySQL statistics

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, statistics

I have a MySQL database with a table of statistics. I want to output the data in an annual calendar, monthly. For months in which no hits are present I want to spend an "empty" DIV. There are two ID.

```
$query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT `id`, MONTH(`date`) AS `month`, COUNT(*) AS `quant`
FROM `statistic` WHERE YEAR(`date`) = '2014' && `k_id` = '12345' group by `id`, `month`");

while($xyz = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {
if($old != $xyz->id) {
if($old=='') {
    echo '<div class="statistic“>‘.“\n“;
}
else {
    echo '</div>'."\n";
    echo '<div class="statistic“>‘.“\n“;
}
$old = $xyz->id;
}
echo '<div class="'.$ausgabe->month.’“>’.$xyz-> quant.'</div>'."\n";
}
```

My result:

```
<div class="statistic">
<div class="6">11</div>
<div class="7">6</div>
<div class="8">20</div>
</div>
<div class="statistic">
<div class="7">1</div>
<div class="8">8</div>
</div>
```

What i want:

```
<div class="statistic">
<div class="1">0</div>
<div class="2">0</div>
<div class="3">0</div>
<div class="4">0</div>
<div class="5">0</div>
<div class="6">11</div>
<div class="7">6</div>
<div class="8">20</div>
<div class="9">0</div>
<div class="10">0</div>
<div class="11">0</div>
<div class="12">0</div>
</div>

<div class="statistic">
<div class="1">0</div>
<div class="2">0</div>
<div class="3">0</div>
<div class="4">0</div>
<div class="5">0</div>
<div class="6">0</div>
<div class="7">1</div>
<div class="8">8</div>
<div class="9">0</div>
<div class="10">0</div>
<div class="11">0</div>
<div class="12">0</div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your code to the following, since you know ahead of time how many months you'll want to be present.

```
$statArr = array();
while($xyz = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {
    $statArr[(int)$xyz->month] = $xyz->quant;
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    echo '<div class="' . $i . '">' . (isset($statArr[$i]) ? $statArr[$i] : 0) . '</div>'
}
```

A few notes. First of all, classes starting with numbers are not valid CSS classnames. Secondly, if you're not familiar with the shorthand if-else statement, it's calls a ternary operation. If the `$statArr` has the index, use it. Otherwise output a zero.

Comment: The notes are known to me and are only used in the test environment. Unfortunately I do not get the result yet. It can, as described, occur several ID. Year View must be generated for each ID. With your script, unfortunately I get hits from different ID ...

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're saying. "Year View must be generated for each ID," but where does the ID come from?